# Number of 0's in a sorted boolean n*n matrix in log(n) time

Tags: algorithm, search, matrix

This is a google interview question.

You are given a matrix with N rows and N columns. Elements in matrix can be either 1 or 0. Each row and column of matrix is sorted in ascending order. Find number of 0-s in the given matrix.

I had come up with a O(n) solution, but not able to at all come with a O(logn) solution. Any pointers are highly appreciated.

EDIT: It seems O(logn) seems not possible, as explained below.

Comment: show your O(n) solution

Comment: Are you sure this is actually doable in worst-case complexity O(log n)? May it be that you forgot some hypothesis of the problem? Or maybe you are talking about average-case complexity

Comment: show us your code... I think that is impossible

Comment: Here is a O(n) solution: assuming the indexes go from 1 to n, starting with i=n, j=1 do: if the element is 1 then i--, if it is 0 then j++. This way you identify all the "pivots", i.e. the first 1 in each row (you got a pivot whenever you change from moving horizontally to moving vertically). This requires at most 2n steps.

Comment: @Saphrosit sorry, but I don't get your algorithm... pls post a link to your code or an example or something... to me it makes no sense

Comment: @Thomas sorry but right now I don't have time to show a full working example (also, that wouldn't answer the OP in any way). As you are saying in your answer you got to find the position in each row where the 0 turns into 1. Your algorithm does not exploit the fact that the matrix is also sorted by columns. My solution simply follows "the path of 1s": starting from bottom left element move right or up according to whether you found a 0 or a 1. Hope it's clearer now. If it is not, try to write down a matrix as in the OP and follow my solution.

Comment: @Saphrosit Ahh... I think I got the question wrong... I thought each row is sorted, but I didn't got, that the zeros are like a triangle inside the matrix... now it makes totally sense! THX @ Saphrosit

Answer (score 2):

First, here is an algorithm that counts the zeroes in *O(n)* time:

```
countZeroes(matrix):
    n = matrix.rowCount
    i = 0
    j = n-1
    count = 0
    while i < n && j >=0:
        if matrix[i][j] == 1 then:
            j--
        else:
            i++
            count += j+1
    return count
```

As each iteration either increments **i** or decrements **j**, and both can only take values between **0..n-1** before the loop ends, the maximum number of iterations is **2n**, which is *O(n)*.

Here is a JavaScript snippet that generates a 5x5 random matrix and counts the zeroes with the above algorithm:

```js
    function countZeroes(matrix) {
        var n = matrix.length,
            i = 0,
            j = n-1,
            count = 0;
        while (i < n && j >=0) {
            if (matrix[i][j] === 1) {
                j--;
            } else {
                i++;
                count += j+1;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    function randomMatrix(n) {
        var matrix = [],
            zeroCounts = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            zeroCounts[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * (n+1));
        }
        zeroCounts.sort((a,b) => b-a); // descending
        for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            matrix[i] = [];
            for (var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                matrix[i][j] = j < zeroCounts[i] ? 0 : 1;
            }
        }
        return matrix;
    }

    function matrixToString(matrix) {
        var s = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            s += matrix[i].join('') + '\n';
        }
        return s;
    }

    var matrix = randomMatrix(5);
    console.log(matrixToString(matrix));
    console.log('Zeroes: ', countZeroes(matrix));
```

#### Can it be done in *O(log n)*?

Imagine a matrix like this:

```
0000
0001
0011
0111
```

You will need to visit every row in this matrix to know how many zeroes there are in it. Imagine you would visit only 3 of the 4 rows: it could be any 3... There would still be at least three possible outcomes for the total number of zeroes unless you also visit that fourth one.

For instance if you would have visited row 0, row 1 and row 3, you would know this:

```
0000
0001
****
0111
```

By the fact that the rows and columns are sorted, you can deduct:

```
0000
0001
0**1
0111
```

But the remaining `**` could be `00`, `01` or `11`. The only way to find out is to actually look at at least one value in that row.

Conclusion: it is not possible in less than *O(n)*.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say in the course of the algorithm we have already learned that the matrix is of the following form:

```
000?
00?1
0?11
?111
```

We cannot learn the value of any ? from the value of any other ?, so we need to look at each one of them. Thus, any solution to the general problem needs at least O(*n*) time, and a solution in log(*n*) or log²(*n*) time is impossible.

Comment: This is true, but this is not how you learn things. Suppose M(2,2) = 0 then you learn that M(0..2,0..2) = 0. Suppose M(2,2) = 0 and M(3,2) = 1 then you learn that M(0..2,0..2) = 0 and M(3..n,2..n) = 1

Comment: @LiorKogan Yes, that's how the improvement from O(n^2) to O(n) works. The `?` squares in the example above have no order relations like this.

Answer (score 0):

using binary search to find number of zeros in a row could help out here!

```
public static int findZerosV2(int[][] NxNMatrix) {
    int numZeros = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < NxNMatrix.length; i++) {
        int numZerosInRow = binarySearch(NxNMatrix[i]);
        if (numZerosInRow > -1) {
            numZeros += numZerosInRow;
        }
    }
    return numZeros;
}

public static int binarySearch(int[] rowItem) {
    int foundZeros = -1;
    int rowIndex = 0;
    int highIndex = rowItem.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < rowItem.length; i++) {
        //find the middle element 
        int mIndex = (rowIndex + highIndex) / 2;
        if (rowItem[mIndex] == 0) {
            rowIndex = mIndex + 1;
            //keep count using index number of 0
            foundZeros = mIndex;
        } else
            highIndex = mIndex - 1;
    }
    //considering zero based index array
    return foundZeros + 1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use a binarysearch on every row to find the position where 0 changes to 1.
Binarysearch is working on an sorted array in O(log n). you will get out the indexnumber of the changed position. this you should do for every row (n times) and then the time will be O(n* log n)

Comment: btw: here is a link to binarysearch: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

Comment: O(n*log n) is worse than O(n), which is worse than O(log n), which is what the OP is asking for. Besides, the author claims to have already a O(n) algorithm

Comment: I think it is not possible in O(n) because O(n) you need to iterate over all rows, also that means that O(1) would be like figuring out where the change from 0 to 1 inside one row is... that is impossible...

Comment: answered in a comment to the OP

Answer (score -1):

Binary search the "middle" point on the anti-diagonal, then you'll know that the upper-left sub-matrix is full of 0 and the lower-right full of 1. Recursive search on lower-left and lower-right sub-matrices?

Comment: what does it mean to "Use a binary search on first (or last depending on the sort) element of each row"? Do you mean a binary search on the first column? If it is the case, then your solution is not working. Simply consider the case where only the first row and first column are 0s.